# Mouseleave event on SVG in Microsoft Edge

Tags: d3.js, svg, event-handling, microsoft-edge, mouseleave

I've built a data-visualization using d3.js v4 that works fine on Chrome, Safari, and Firefox, but (typically) am running into problems with Windows browsers.

Basically, the mouseleave event is not firing for the visualization when the user moves his mouse off of an SVG circle, which means the svg remains highlighted and enlarged. Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
d3.selectAll("circle").on("mouseleave", hideData)

function hideData(d) {

// None of this code is working on Edge...

d3.select("#toolTip")
  .transition().style("opacity",0)

d3.select(this)
   .transition()
   .attr("r", function(){
    var radius
    if(Math.sqrt((d.Claims)/Math.PI) > 1){
        radius = Math.sqrt((d.Claims)/Math.PI)
    }
    else { radius = 1}
    return radius
   })   
   .style("fill", d => colorScale(d.Type))

    d3.selectAll("circle").style("fill", b => colorScale(b.Type))
}
```

Is there a way I can change the code so that it will work on Windows browsers?

Comment: A simple example using your code works just fine in Edge: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Jag/3081/  Please post a working example that doesn't.